# Using Sumif and vlookup of a partial string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So basically i have a data table and a mapping table. 
The mapping table determines which class each of the category falls into by looking at a partial string. I then calculate the total values that falls into the same class.

While i know i can do this by simply adding in a vlookup/index match column on my data table. is there a way to accomplish the output using a single formula?

The reason is that the original data table contains other columns that a bunch of vba code relies on, therefore i do not want to amend that table if possible.

Data Table:

```
Name        Values
dog1        2
dog2        3
dog3        4
cat1        1
cat2        2
trout1      5
trout2      6
trout3      7
```

Mapping Table:

```
Category    Class
dog         pet
trout       fish
cat         pet
```

Output:

```
Class Total
pet   12
```

Comment: you probably mean for output class to be "pet", not "dog", right?

Comment: Ah, yes. pet. Amended. thank you!

Comment: I'm thinking something like this might be an alternative but haven't got time to test it =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A2:A5,"\*"&IF(D2:D4="pet",C2:C4,)&"\*",B2:B5))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ca be made to work by array formulae but I wouldn't say it was elegant.

A fairly standard formula for listing the distinct class values

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(E$2:$E$10,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($G1:$G$1,$E$2:INDEX($E$2:$E$10,COUNTA($E$2:$E$10))),0)),"")
```

Then a SUMIF for each different class value mapped into its corresponding category values, enclosed in a SUM to get the total for all categories

```
=IF(G2="","",SUM(SUMIF($A$2:$A$10,"*"&IF($E$2:$E$10=G2,$D$2:$D$10,"~~~")&"*",$B$2:$B$10)))
```

[image]

Comment: I agree with the "not elegant" bit and would like to add "not easily maintainable". The wildcard aspect will only work as long as the name and the category share the same starting letters and it might fall over when there is ambiguity like "catfish". Also, the Power Pivot approach will still be very easy to grasp 6 months down the track, by which time the logic of the formula will have completely been forgotten.

Comment: Yes, yes and yes (although SUMIF/SUM is a fairly recognisable pattern). I just wanted to make the point that it _could_ be done with a formula rather than that it _should_  be.

Answer (score 3):

Try this scenario:

Look up the category for the class with an Index/Match, append a wildcard character and put that into a Sumif function. The formula in cell H3 is as follows, copied down.

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$7,INDEX($D$3:$D$4,MATCH(G3,$E$3:$E$4,0))&"*",$B$2:$B$7)
```

[image]

Edit after comment: If multiple categories are mapped to the same class, a formula solution is no longer viable. Instead, consider using Power Pivot and the Excel data model with relationships between the tables. You will need the following tables:

- initial data entry table with Name and value
- a table that maps Name to Category
- a table that maps Category to class

Then you can add these tables to the Data Model in Power Pivot and define the relationships.[image][image]

Now you can build a pivot table with the class from the Category/Class table that sums up the values from the initial data entry table.

Power Pivot is a free add-in for Excel 2010 to 2013 and built into enterprise versions of Excel 2016.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. However, your formula works if there's only one "Category" linked to "Class". Say for e.g. if I add in a new "Category" of "cat" that is under "pet" as well. the formula only return the first instance of "pet" it sees then just stops there. 

is there a way around this where i get all instances of pet? 

modified table with "cat" added: 
[link](http://imgur.com/a/9OoGf)

Comment: i've amended the qn. hopefully it'll make things clearer.

Comment: I've added a working solution with Power Pivot. Formulas will not cut it in this scenario.